# Deleting data without refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs

So I have created a delete method for my crud app in react. My delete method works but in order for the data to disappear I always have to refresh the page. What are some ways I could do to fix this issue. Below is my delete method code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
export default class TableRow extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 this.deletestudent = this.deletestudent.bind(this);
}
deletestudent() {
        axios.post('http://localhost:3200/students/deleteStudent', {
            '_id': this.props.object._id
        })
            .then(console.log('Student Deleted'))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  render(){
    return(
      <tr>
            <td>{this.props.object._id}</td>
            <td>{this.props.object.role_num} </td>
             <td>{this.props.object.first_name}</td>
            <td>{this.props.object.last_name}</td>
            <td>{this.props.object.marks}</td>
          <td> <Link to ={"/editform/"+ this.props.object._id} className = 'btn-btn-danger'>Update</Link> </td>
            <td> <button onClick={this.deletestudent} className = 'btn-btn-danger'>Remove</button></td>
     </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not remove the line after the AJAX call has succeeded?

Comment: which line the catch line

Comment: What do you mean by that question?

Comment: which line do I remove

Comment: Well, that table row that you want to remove without reloading the page?

Comment: .catch(err => console.log(err)); remove this line

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have something which keeps the list of students. In the following code example, I named it `Table`. It loads the data and handles deletion of single items. If you edit data, you might also add a handler for it into the `Table`, so **everything is in sync**.

```
import React, {Component, useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function Table() {

    const [students, updateStudents] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3200/students')
            .then((response) => response.JSON())
            .then((studentsResp) => updateStudents(studentsResp))
    }, []);


    const onRemoveStudent = useCallback((student) => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:3200/students/deleteStudent', {
            '_id': student._id
        })
            .then(console.log('Student Deleted'))
            .then(() => {
                let newStudentsArr = students;
                const index = newStudentsArr.findIndex((obj) => obj._id === student._id);
                newStudentsArr.splice(index, 1);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, []);

    return <table>
        {students.map((student, index) => {
            <TableRow key={index} object={student} onRemove={onRemoveStudent} />
        })}
    </table>


}

export default class TableRow extends Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.object._id}</td>
                <td>{this.props.object.role_num} </td>
                <td>{this.props.object.first_name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.object.last_name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.object.marks}</td>
                <td> <Link to ={"/editform/"+ this.props.object._id} className = 'btn-btn-danger'>Update</Link> </td>
                <td> <button onClick={() => this.props.onRemove(this.props.object)} className = 'btn-btn-danger'>Remove</button></td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Table from './components/Table';

const App = () => {
    return <div>
        <h2>Your App</h2>
        {/* other code from yours */}
        <Table />
    </div>
}


const root = document.getElementById('root'); 
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

Comment: where is Table defined

Comment: I mean where is the function Table used

Comment: `Table` is just another react component. Use it in `ReactDOM.render(<Table />, domRoot)` or somewhere else in your React tree.

Comment: just show me a full code on where I can place the Table component

Comment: ok so this is my App.test.js file import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
  ReactDOM.render(<Table />, domRoot);
});
this is where I put it but it is saying it is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get your list of student from? One simple way to solve this is to, inside the .then() of your delete function, call your list of students again

Remember: everytime you change state the page rerenders, so everything inside render() will be executed again. Use that in your favor